# How to calculate the position of custom scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table and i created own scrollbar for iPad in my project.

Now, the table is moving as the user touch and drag it, but how to move my scrollbar according to that table.

I tried but for me its working very strange.
For example, if table moves right, then my scrollbar moving left. Since i am not good in Math, i cant do the calculation correctly.

how can i make my scrollbar ( scrolldiv1 and scrolldiv2 ) work perfectly in iPad ?

This is my code that i tried. `plnkr.co/edit/KeKvldo3KdiC9JF5VMTH?p=preview`

I don't want to use any plugins for a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Get Height and Width of your Table using $("myTable").height() and width... Make ur Scroll one tenth of of the the total height and and div and divide it, you can use jQuery animate to animate the content and Scroll divs...

Also using .scrollTop() can make the code much simpler, for more info visit: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop

Hope it helps...